# While-loop reading csv file out of bounds

Tags: java, csv, while-loop

I am working on a program that reads from a file with a list of bank accounts. I keep encountering an IndexOutOfBoundsException error and I'm not sure why. When I put the bank accounts straight in the code (not reading from a file) it works just fine which leads me to believe that my while-loop is messed up somewhere. I suspect that it is not looping correctly but I am not positive. I don't have very much experience with while-loops unfortunately.

File I am reading from, listed in order of accountType/name/worth/rate:

```
1,Waterford Ellingsworth,4350.0,0.002
2,Bethanie Treadwell,500.0,0.35
3,Ira Standish,50000,0.1,59,0.1
```

The actual program itself:

```
 Scanner infile = new Scanner("‪C:/Users/Josh/Desktop/prog5input.csv");
    while (infile.hasNextLine()) {
        Scanner s2 = new Scanner(infile.nextLine()); // put string from file into second Scanner object
        s2.useDelimiter(",");
        if (s2.hasNextInt()) {
            int type = s2.nextInt(); 
            if (type == 1) {
                String accountHolder = s2.next();
                double accountInitial = s2.nextDouble();
                double accountRate = s2.nextDouble();
                bank.addNewAccount(new SavingsAccount(accountHolder, accountInitial, accountRate));
                // read fields for Type 1 accounts and create new Type 1 object
            }
            else if (type == 2) {
                String accountHolder = s2.next();
                double accountInitial = s2.nextDouble();
                double accountCostPerMonth = s2.nextDouble();
                bank.addNewAccount(new CheckingAccount(accountHolder, accountInitial, accountCostPerMonth));
            }
            else if (type == 3) {
                String accountHolder = s2.next();
                double accountInitial = s2.nextDouble();
                double accountRate = s2.nextDouble();
                int disbursementAge = s2.nextInt();
                double earlyWithdrawalPenalty = s2.nextDouble();
                bank.addNewAccount(new IRAAccount(accountHolder, accountInitial, accountRate, disbursementAge, earlyWithdrawalPenalty));
            }
        } //ends if statement s2.hasNextInt()
        // now go to top of loop, check infile to see if there is another line to read
    } //ends while loop
```

Edited to include the output:

```
Creating accounts...

Performing transactions...
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
    at Bank.getAccountByIndex(Bank.java:28)
    at BankDriverFileInput.main(BankDriverFileInput.java:58)
```

Here's a link to my entire program: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0BysdkYqrEP7kazNhMXpQSzd4bUE?usp=sharing

Comment: `Scanner infile = new Scanner("‪C:/Users/Josh/Desktop/prog5input.csv");` scans the filename, not the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace

```
Scanner infile = new Scanner("‪C:/Users/Josh/Desktop/prog5input.csv");
```

with

```
Scanner infile = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("‪C:/Users/Josh/Desktop/prog5input.csv"));
```

beacuse as your code, the *inputstream* of Scanner will be  **String** "c:...." rather than the **file** it represents.

Comment: When I do that I get the error 

    Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: ‪C:\Users\Josh\Desktop\prog5input.csv (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)

Comment: @Josh Correia  use '/' or '\\' as C:\\Users\\...   beacuse '\' is escaped characte.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded your google drive programs and it worked for me with charm with following change..

```
Scanner infile = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("‪C://Users//Josh//Desktop//prog5input.csv"));
```

Make sure you have specified correct file path here..

### My sample output for your reference:

Program 5, Josh Correia, cssc0491
Creating accounts...
Waterford Ellingsworth4350.00.002Customer: Waterford Ellingsworth, Savings account 1 Balance: $4350.00
Customer: Bethanie Treadwell, Checking account 2 Balance: $500.00
Customer: Ira Standish, IRA Savings account 3 Balance: $50000.00, Disbursement Age=59, Early Withdrawal Penalty=0.1

Performing transactions...
Savings account 1 Balance: $4550.00
Checking account 2 Balance: $286.87
IRA Savings account 3 Balance: $50000.00, Disbursement Age=59, Early Withdrawal Penalty=0.1

Updating accounts...
Savings account 1 Balance: $4559.10
Checking account 2 Balance: $286.52
IRA Savings account 3 Balance: $55000.00, Disbursement Age=59, Early Withdrawal Penalty=0.1